# Redirecting syslogd Error Messages to an Error Log or to a Null File?

Tags: debian, terminal, io-redirection, syslog

I have an old PowerPC laptop (old Mac Powerbook G4) that I am running a variant of Debian Squeeze on (MintPPC 9).

I keep getting Kernel error messages when I am connected to a particular wireless network but not at other times. I suspect, but have not proven, that it is arising from the networking module. The error messages overwhelm anything I am doing at the time (e.g. overlaying a CLI Emacs display) but do not otherwise seem to influence the function of the machine, even the networking seems to soldier on.

Is there a way to redirect error messages from syslogd specifically to an error log or possibly `/dev/null` but to leave other error messages going to `stdout`. I know that `2>>` will direct error messages but since I did not consciously start syslogd I don't know how to do so.

Sometimes the error messages are more elaborate but here is an example:

```
Message form syslogd@debian at Dec 10 09:48:02 ...
 kernel:[   720.749515] -----------[  cut here  ]---------------
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're experiencing is a [`wall`ed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_(Unix)) message.

Debian's default `syslog` daemon, [`rsyslog`](http://wiki.debian.org/Rsyslog), will with the default configuration send messages with severity `emerg` from any facility (`*`) to *all logged in users*, via `wall` (from `/etc/rsyslog.conf`):

```
#
# Emergencies are sent to everybody logged in.
#
*.emerg                         :omusrmsg:*
```

You can change this by [configuring Rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf.html) to do something else.

For example (though I'm not sure if it's really advisable to make emergency messages ignorable) you could change the `/var/log/messages` *catch-all rule* (above the `*.emerg`)

```
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        cron,daemon.none;\
        mail,news.none          -/var/log/messages
```

to also catch `*.emerg` and comment out the rule below.